# How to manage JWT access and refresh tokens client side

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, netflix-zuul

I am developing a microservice based application using Zuul as the API gateway but I have some concerns related to the security system.
At the moment I have a layer of security developed using spring security that sits just in front of the zuul gateway. This means that every microservice behind is free from authentication/authorization logic, because it is performed at zuul level. 
The user basically provides his credentials to the Authentication service that produces and returns the access and refresh tokens to the client.
For each subsequent request to the protected API exposed by the microservices the client sends the access token that, if validated, allow the access.
Whenever the access token expires, the client uses the refresh token to get a new access token.
My problem is where to store these tokens client side. I thought of storing the access token in memory because of its very limited duration (10 minutes), and the refresh token in a httponly cookie protected against CSRF.
Another problem is that the same resources can be accessed from a mobile application and a web site. As far as I know the mobile doesn't need to be protected against CSRF.
How would you manage such a scenario? How should these tokens be managed client side?